# Django: how to change the choices of AdminTimeWidget

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

The `AdminTimeWidget` rendered in admin for a `DateTimeField` displays an icon of a clock and when you click you have the choice between: "Now Midnight 6:00 Noon".

How can I change these choices to "16h 17h 18h"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chris has a great answer.  As an alternative you could do this using just javascript.  Place the following javascript on the pages where you want the different time options.

```
DateTimeShortcuts.overrideTimeOptions = function () {
    // Find the first time element
    timeElement = django.jQuery("ul.timelist li").eq(0).clone();
    originalHref = timeElement.find('a').attr('href');

    // remove all existing time elements
    django.jQuery("ul.timelist li").remove();

    // add new time elements representing those you want
    var i=0;
    for (i=0;i<=23;i++) {
        // use a regular expression to update the link
        newHref = originalHref.replace(/Date\([^\)]*\)/g, "Date(1970,1,1," + i + ",0,0,0)");
        // update the text for the element
        timeElement.find('a').attr('href', newHref).text(i+"h");
        // Add the new element into the document
        django.jQuery("ul.timelist").append(timeElement.clone());
    }
}

addEvent(window, 'load', DateTimeShortcuts.overrideTimeOptions);
```

Comment: Actually, that's pretty elegant. Since the only point in subclassing is to override the JS being used, your approach is actually probably the better one.

Comment: Thanks, I liked your solution too. My solution uses less code, but seems less intentional than yours.  I tried to think which solution would be easier to maintain over time, in particular as Django itself is upgraded.  I liked yours because it made it very clear what was happening.  I liked that mine could be implemented without duplicating any of the Django files.  I couldn't really figure out which way was more maintainable so I thought I'd post the solution and let the crowd evaluate this approach.

Comment: In Django 4.2 this can be done with one line of Javascript:  `DateTimeShortcuts.clockHours.default_= [['8 AM', 8],['9 AM', 9],['10 AM', 10],`...etc.  But since DateTimeShortcuts.js uses `Date(1970,1,1,val,0,0,0)` to evaluate, I don't see a way to include half-hours in the list, e.g. 9:30, 10:30.

Answer (score 10):

Subclass `AdminTimeWidget` to include a modified DateTimeShortcuts.js (get to that in a sec), then subclass `AdminSplitDateTime` to include your subclassed `MyAdminTimeWidget` instead of the default Django one:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminTimeWidget
from django.conf import settings

class MyAdminTimeWidget(AdminTimeWidget):
    class Media:
        js = (settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX + "js/calendar.js",
              settings.MEDIA_URL + "js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js")

class MyAdminSplitDateTime(AdminSplitDateTime):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        widgets = [AdminDateWidget, MyAdminTimeWidget]
        forms.MultiWidget.__init__(self, widgets, attrs)
```

The secret sauce is in `django/contrib/admin/media/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js`. This is what creates the list you want to modify. Copy this file and paste it into your project's `site_media/js/admin` directory.  The relevant code you need to modify is on lines 85-88:

```
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("Now"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date().strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("Midnight"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("6 a.m."), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,6,0,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("Noon"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,12,0,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
```

Simply add to/delete from/modify that bit of javascript to your heart's content.

Finally, attach your new widget to any DateTimeFields you like. Your best bet for that will probably be the `formfield_overrides` attribute on `ModelAdmin`:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.DateTimeField: {'widget': MyAdminSplitDateTime},
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried using this method and found the above javascript didn't work when multiple datetime's were present on the form.

here is what I did.

In my ModelAdmin section i added:

```
class Media:
    js = ('js/clock_time_selections.js',)
```

then in the js file:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    DateTimeShortcuts.overrideTimeOptions = function () {
        var clockCount = 0;
        console.log('ready');
        $('ul.timelist').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var originalHref = $this.find('a').attr('href');
            console.log(originalHref);
            $this.find('li').remove();
            for (i=8; i <= 20; i++) {
                var newLink = '<li><a href="javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink('+ clockCount + ', ' + i
                    + ');"> ' + i + ':00h</a></li>';
                $this.append(newLink);
            }
            //console.log($this.html());

            clockCount++;
        });
    };

    addEvent(window, 'load', DateTimeShortcuts.overrideTimeOptions);
});
```

Note: i had to put inside a document.ready because i found that i couldn't control where the script was included in the page (seems to have be loaded before the default calendar js files).

Answer (score 5):

There's better solution. After reading [DateTimeShortcuts.js](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js) the can be simplified to:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        DateTimeShortcuts.clockHours.default_ = [];

        for (let hour = 8; hour <= 20; hour++) {
            let verbose_name = new Date(1970, 1, 1, hour, 0, 0).strftime('%H:%M');
            DateTimeShortcuts.clockHours.default_.push([verbose_name, hour])
        }

    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Then add this code to the javascript file in 'static//time-shortcuts.js' and add Meta to your admin model:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = [
            '<myapp>/time-shortcuts.js',
        ]
```

Comment: It worked for me when I deleted first and least lines in JavaScript code.

Answer (score 3):

I went with a much simpler approach and it worked for me. I simply added choices to my model using the following code:

`class Class(Model):
    program = ForeignKey('Program')
    time_of_the_day = TimeField(choices=(
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('7:00 am', "%I:%M %p").time(), '7:00 am'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('8:00 am', "%I:%M %p").time(), '8:00 am'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('9:00 am', "%I:%M %p").time(), '9:00 am'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('6:00 pm', "%I:%M %p").time(), '6:00 pm'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('7:00 pm', "%I:%M %p").time(), '7:00 pm'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('8:00 pm', "%I:%M %p").time(), '8:00 pm'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('9:00 pm', "%I:%M %p").time(), '9:00 pm'),

    ))`

Hope this helps

Comment: Are you sure? I received an error stating that `choices` is an invalid option for `TimeField`

Comment: Worked for me back in 2015, maybe the current version doesn't allow it. The project with this snippet is still up and running tho.

Comment: I have to check it again in case I misspelled something, your idea is great.

Comment: nice answer! straight to the point

Answer (score 1):

Overriding JS by *DateTimeShortcuts.overrideTimeOptions* function works only with one form
 ( bug: the change of time in child model affects parent model, so you can't change timefield in child model form by this widget)

If you want use custom time options with inlines:

in */static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js* 
replace:

```
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("Now"), "href",    "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date().strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("Midnight"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("6 a.m."), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,6,0,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("Noon"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,12,0,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
```

by:

```
for(j=6;j<=23;j++){
    quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), j+":00", "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1," + j + ",0,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Bit68's answer, assuming other folks might want to create lists of regularly spaced times more than once, I created a helper function to build a choices tuple.  (I'm adding a new answer because this length of code is too hard to follow in a comment.)  This works in Django 2.2.

Note that this creates a dropdown list of options, it doesn't add options to the default admin date/time widget as the javascript methods do.

```
import datetime

def get_time_choices(start_time=datetime.time(9,0,0), end_time=datetime.time(17,0,0), delta=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)):
    '''
        Builds a choices tuple of (time object, time string) tuples
        starting at the start time specified and ending at or before 
        the end time specified in increments of size delta.

        The default is to return a choices tuple for 
        9am to 5pm in 15-minute increments.
    '''
    time_choices = ()
    time = start_time
    while time <= end_time:
        time_choices += ((time, time.strftime("%I:%M %p")),)
        # This complicated line is because you can't add
        # a timedelta object to a time object.
        time = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), time) + delta).time()
    return time_choices
```

Then `time_of_the_day = models.TimeField(choices=get_time_choices())`

Answer (score 0):

After checking the source code of DateTimeShortcuts.js I found quite easy to overwrite the function that handles `DateTimeShortcuts.clockHours.default_` and make it manage also floats like `16.5` (for "16:30"). I can now do much more, like synchronizing two time inputs (as I have two start_at and end_at fields):

```py
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    (function ($) {
        DateTimeShortcuts.clockHours.default_ = [
            ['16:30', 16.5],
            ['17:30', 17.5],
            ['18:00', 18],
            ['19:00', 19],
            ['20:00', 20],
        ];

        DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink = function (num, val) {
            let d;
            if (val == -1) {
                d = DateTimeShortcuts.now();
            } else {
                const h = val | 0;
                const m = (val - h) * 60;
                d = new Date(1970, 1, 1, h, m, 0, 0);
            }
            DateTimeShortcuts.clockInputs[num].value = d.strftime(get_format('TIME_INPUT_FORMATS')[0]);
            DateTimeShortcuts.clockInputs[num].focus();
            DateTimeShortcuts.dismissClock(num);
        };
    })(django.jQuery);
});
```