# Overloading DateTimeShortcuts.js in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Simple question really, is there any programmatic way to over load the "choose a time" options in django for the DateTimeShortcuts.js when used in the admin?

The options they present aren't very helpful the last option of the day is noon.  I was hoping to have every hour of the day as an option

Comment: I think you're going to have to created a custom datetime widget for the django-admin.

Comment: Yes that is what my investigations so far seem to suggest, I was hoping there was a cleaner solution. Thanks all the same

Comment: Here is a duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770973/django-how-to-change-the-choices-of-admintimewidget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I had to edit the widget contained in the django install (... site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js).  I was getting confused as even when I edited it, it was not working.  It was my fault, as even though I was working on a local machine the settings were still pointing to the remote server for the media files, so editing the local didn't show any effect, fixed that and it worked.