# Changing the default times in the Django TimeInput

Tags: python, django

I am writing a small application in Django to help our training department manage training classes. I have a model called Schedule that holds the scheduled days for a specific class.

Schedule

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    scheduled_class = models.ForeignKey(ScheduledClass)
    class_date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.class_date)
```

The `Schedule` object is displayed inline with the `ScheduledClass` object so that the user can add class dates when the class is created.

I do not like the feel of the default `TimeInput` widget, it is a little awkward for the user to enter a time because it needs to be entered as `07:00:00` for 7 AM.

To the right of the `TimeInput` widget there is a clock icon that contains the following:

```
Now
Midnight
6 AM
Noon
```

Is there a way to specify different values? There are probably only a handful of values that I am interested in such as `07:00`, `08:00`, `12:00`, `12:30`, `16:00`, `16:30`.

Comment: Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770973/django-how-to-change-the-choices-of-admintimewidget), perhaps?

Comment: My Google skills need help apparently. Make this an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: No worries; the only thing, though, is that both questions are pretty similar (at least from my perspective...) and if the answers from the other question end up working for you, I'm not sure if this question needs to stick around... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own widget..or other workaround is override..putting in your static files the  file : " admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js " (override / http://d.pr/i/uXsL) and change modifyDateTimeShortcut plugin. In your case only replace this:

```
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("Now"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date().strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("Midnight"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");

...
```

For:

```
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("Now"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date().strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("07:00"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,7,0,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("12:00"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,12,0,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("12:30"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,12,30,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("16:00"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,16,0,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");
quickElement("a", quickElement("li", time_list, ""), gettext("16:30"), "href", "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", new Date(1970,1,1,16,30,0,0).strftime('" + time_format + "'));");

...
```

Result:

http://d.pr/i/3ZmW

And here the complete code: https://gist.github.com/hannicolas/8551106

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

You can refrain from using the widget and use a simple drop down using the choices argument as follows:

`class Class(Model):
    program = ForeignKey('Program')
    time_of_the_day = TimeField(choices=(
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('7:00 am', "%I:%M %p").time(), '7:00 am'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('8:00 am', "%I:%M %p").time(), '8:00 am'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('9:00 am', "%I:%M %p").time(), '9:00 am'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('6:00 pm', "%I:%M %p").time(), '6:00 pm'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('7:00 pm', "%I:%M %p").time(), '7:00 pm'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('8:00 pm', "%I:%M %p").time(), '8:00 pm'),
        (datetime.datetime.strptime('9:00 pm', "%I:%M %p").time(), '9:00 pm'),

    ))`

Hope this helps