# Override DateTimeShortcut in Django Admin

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

I'm trying to implement the top solution here, the one that only uses javascript:
[Django: how to change the choices of AdminTimeWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770973/django-how-to-change-the-choices-of-admintimewidget)

It basically uses regex to create the different time choices by overriding the time options.

The only problem I have is that my script loads before DateTimeShortcuts.js, so I get an Uncaught ReferenceError: DateTimeShortcuts is not defined. Does anyone know how I can force the DateTimeShortcuts.js file to load after my js file that references it?

If I create a second reference to DateTimeShortcuts.js, it'll work properly, but I'll have two clocks up there, only the 2nd one will modify, because it's loading after the 2nd DateTimeShortcuts.js

I'm calling my file like this, where admin_clock.js references DateTimeShortcuts.js and has the override code:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('film', 'partner',)
    list_display = ('id', partner', 'film', 'date_time', 'venue_name', 'city')
    class Media:
         js = ('tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', 'tiny_mce/textareas.js', 'admin_clock.js',)
```

Apologies for not commenting on the original answer, I need more points to comment there.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this was to add the javascript directly to the extrahead block of my version of the change_form template, overriding that block in the template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates