# Adding more time options to TimeField admin pull down?

Tags: django

EDIT: comment from PRMoureu put me in the [right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770973/django-how-to-change-the-choices-of-admintimewidget). It turns out that our old django install had been modified by someone previous to me.

I am wondering if it is relatively easy to customize the TimeField pull down menu in django. In older versions the TimeField would show selections for every 30 minutes:

[image]

Django 1.11 only shows a few options:

[image]

Comment: maybe check answers on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770973/django-how-to-change-the-choices-of-admintimewidget)

Comment: thanks - that's exactly what I needed to know. It also turns out that our old install had been modified by someone previous to me.