# Django TimeField Widget change on admin panel

Tags: python, django

I'm working with models.TimeField model which will be shown in admin panel and django time fields is uncomfortable.
[image: Django builtin time widget]

It offers Now, Midnight, Noon keywords. how can i change that, how can i change them to detailed timedeltas? Like this

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: how to change the choices of AdminTimeWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770973/django-how-to-change-the-choices-of-admintimewidget)

Comment: Let me try, it is inside builtin templates